# Como criar um tipo de tela para cada usúario?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

Estou criando um sistema online em tempo real, por enquanto só sei html5/css3/js.. Como faço para assim que o cliente fazer o login as informações dele aparecer para ele e não de outro cliente? Acho que não seria uma boa ideia ficar criando arquivos .html para cada cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é que você crie uma tabela de clientes, por exemplo, e no momento do login você guarda na sessão o Id do cliente logado. Posterior, nas consultas, inserções, alterações... enfim, nas ações no banco de dados, você deve validar o Id do cliente. Por exemplo:

Na tabela de clientes você tem as colunas: Id, Nome, CNPJ, Status.

Na tabela de produtos você tem as colunas: Id, Nome, Peso, Valor, IdCliente.

Na hora de fazer o select de produtos, por exemplo, você vai usar:

```
SELECT C.Nome AS Clietne, P.Nome AS Produto, P.Peso, P.Valor
FROM Produtos P 
INNER JOIN Clientes C ON (P.IdCliente = C.Id)
WHERE P.IdCliente = $_SESSION['sIdCliente']
```

Comment: Muito bom :D la na empresa meu amigo sempre faz isso de guardar a id e usar ela pra tudo, o problema eu acho, e que assim esse dado fica mais vulneravel, nao ? (nao manjo muito de php)

Comment: Eu não vejo vulnerabilidade... acredito que depende muito de toda a estrutura do projeto... não é um valor na sessão que vai deixar o teu projeto vulnerável.

Comment: tendi :D obrigado pelo esclarecimento

Comment: Não esquece de marcar como resposta se resolveu o teu problema ;)